# going from 32 bit to 64 bit in assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

Let's say we have a line in assembly like this:

```
.loop:
      cmp %esi, %rcx
```

I know that one register is used for 32-bit and the other is for 64-bit. But is it possible to turn `%rcx` into 32-bit so that I don't get an error when I try to run the code? I know I can use `ecx` but I wanna see if it's possible to use `%rcx`

Comment: What you're asking to do is not possible and doesn't make sense. You can, however, use %rsi, the 64-bit register whose lower half is %esi. Edit: to be clear, I am suggesting that you perform a 64-bit comparison. Otherwise the question becomes what should comparing a 32-bit and a 64-bit value do? Is the 32-bit value unsigned or signed?

Comment: Hi,

The 32-bit value is unsigned.

Comment: There are 2^64 unique values that can be represented in 64 bits. There are only 2^32 unique values that can be represented in 32 bits. Therefore, trying to store a 64-bit value in a 32-bit variable is going to lose data. The reverse is not true. As it happens, whenever you write a 32-bit register on AMD64, it is zero-extended to 64 bits. If you know that something wrote to %esi, then %rsi is the 64-bit, zero-extended value.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Thanks!

Comment: This question makes no sense.  What *exactly* do you want to happen?  Do you want to compare a sign-extended 32-bit value with a 64-bit value?  Or zero-extend?  You said you don't want to compare the low 32 bits of each value.  Or were you hoping that CF would be set according to zero-extension (unsigned) and OF would be set according to sign-extension (signed)?  That last is not easily possible, and would take many instructions.  Anyway, your question isn't clear on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the 32-bit %ecx register, what you want to do is use the 64-bit %rsi register:

```
.loop:
    cmp %rsi, %rcx
```

Whatever size you use, the register widths must match. 32-bit register writes are always zero-extended and written to the full 64-bit register in AMD64. If you know that %esi was calculated or loaded as a 32-bit value, then %rsi is the same value zero-extended to 64 bits.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now it makes sense, I was worried it wasn't possible because I didn't change the other register to the 64-bit equivalent.